# QuickGraph GraphvizRecord doesn't display in vertices

Tags: graph, graphviz, record, quickgraph

I'm trying to build a Graphviz graph containing record vertices using QuickGraph. So far, I have this:

```
var algo = new GraphvizAlgorithm<Entity, EntityEdge>(this);
algo.CommonVertexFormat.Shape = GraphvizVertexShape.Record;
algo.CommonVertexFormat.Style = GraphvizVertexStyle.Filled;
algo.FormatVertex += new FormatVertexEventHandler<Entity>(FormatVertex);

private void FormatVertex(object sender, FormatVertexEventArgs<Entity> e) {
    Entity ent = e.Vertex;
    GraphvizRecord rec = new GraphvizRecord();

    GraphvizRecordCell rootCell = new GraphvizRecordCell();
    rootCell.Text = ent.ClassName + "\\n" + ent.TargetName;

    var inputs = ent.GetUniqueInputNames();

    foreach (string input in inputs) {
        GraphvizRecordCell cell = new GraphvizRecordCell();
        cell.Text = input;
        cell.Port = input;
        rootCell.Cells.Add(cell);
    }

    rec.Cells.Add(rootCell);

    e.VertexFormatter.Record = rec;
}
```

When I generate the graph, however, the vertices show a label instead of a record. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Here's the dot output.

```
digraph G {
    bgcolor="#454545FF"
    node [fillcolor="#505050FF", color="#2A2A2AFF", shape=record, fontname="Verdana",  fontsize=10, label="", style=filled, fontcolor="#FFFFFFFF"];
    edge [ fontsize=10, fontcolor="#FFFFFFFF", color="#ECA706FF", fontname="Verdana"];
    0 [label="EntityMap.Entity"];
    1 [label="EntityMap.Entity"];
    2 [label="EntityMap.Entity"];
    3 [label="EntityMap.Entity"];
    4 [label="EntityMap.Entity"];
    5 [label="EntityMap.Entity"];
    6 [label="EntityMap.Entity"];
    7 [label="EntityMap.Entity"];
    8 [label="EntityMap.Entity"];
    9 [label="EntityMap.Entity"];
    10 [label="EntityMap.Entity"];
    11 [label="EntityMap.Entity"];
    12 [label="EntityMap.Entity"];
    13 [label="EntityMap.Entity"];
    14 [label="EntityMap.Entity"];
    15 [label="EntityMap.Entity"];
    0 -> 0 [ label="OnPlayerUse", headport="EnableMotion", headlabel=""];
    0 -> 1 [ label="OnPlayerUse", headport="Explode", headlabel=""];
    0 -> 6 [ label="OnPlayerUse", headport="Compare", headlabel=""];
    0 -> 5 [ label="OnPlayerUse", headport="RevertToDefaultRelationship", headlabel=""];
    3 -> 4 [ label="OnTrigger", headport="Wake", headlabel=""];
    4 -> 2 [ label="OnFoundEnemy", headport="Display", headlabel=""];
    6 -> 15 [ label="OnEqualTo", headport="EmitAISound", headlabel=""];
    6 -> 4 [ label="OnEqualTo", headport="Wake", headlabel=""];
    7 -> 8 [ label="OnStartTouch", headport="Command", headlabel="+duck"];
    7 -> 8 [ label="OnEndTouch", headport="Command", headlabel="-duck"];
    7 -> 9 [ label="OnEndTouch", headport="Enable", headlabel=""];
    7 -> 10 [ label="OnEndTouch", headport="Fade", headlabel=""];
    7 -> 7 [ label="OnEndTouch", headport="Disable", headlabel=""];
    12 -> 11 [ label="OnMapSpawn", headport="Fade", headlabel=""];
    13 -> 6 [ label="OnPass", headport="SetValue", headlabel="1"];
    14 -> 6 [ label="OnPass", headport="SetValue", headlabel="1"];
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the `dot` source of the rendered graph? It might provide clues...

Comment: I've added the dot output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are details missing in the root cells, specifically the names of the object methods. I guess the `dot`output line

```
0 [label="EntityMap.Entity"];
```

...should really be:

```
0 [label="<EnableMotion> EntityMap.Entity"];
```

(...and I guess they shouldn't all be named `EntityMap.Entity`?)

I cannot really tell where in your program the edges are introduced, but it seems like the edges are rendered based on different information than the vertices.

Running `dot` manually (`dot foo.dot -Tpng -o foo.png`) might give you more informative error/warning messages.

Comment: Well, the dot output is wrong because that's the way QuickGraph is generating it. I'm setting everything up to use records and cells, but QuickGraph is ignoring me and using labels instead.